# What can I do with the money deposited into my Blizzard account from selling gear on the RMAH?

Tags: diablo-iii

... other than spending it in the RMAH?

I am only intending on selling stuff on the RMAH, so I am just wondering what can I realistically do with the money I've earned from it, since I can't seem to convert it into cold hard cash? I've opted for the Blizzard account option as the Paypal option charges an extra 15% on top of the $1 transaction fee.

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote? I am sure I am not going to be the only one to wonder about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO, the best thing to do is pay the 15% Paypal fee, so you can actually do stuff with the money earned right now (if you do not plan to buy items or any of the Blizzard services below anyways..).

From the official [Battle.net Balance FAQ](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battle-net-balance-faq):

> With Battle.net Balance, you can purchase:
>
> World of Warcraft Character Services
>
> - Appearance Change
> - Faction Change
> - Name Change
> - Race Change
> - Realm Transfer
>
> World of Warcraft Guild Services
>
> - Guild Faction Change
> - Guild Name Change
> - Guild Realm Transfer
> - Guild Faction Change + Guild Name Change
> - Guild Realm Transfer + Guild Faction Change + Guild Name Change
> - Guild Realm Transfer + Guild Name Change
>
> World of Warcraft Digital Upgrades
>
> - WoW: Battle Chest to Wrath of the Lich King
> - WoW: Battle Chest to Cataclysm
> - Wrath of the Lich King to Cataclysm
>
> Other Digital Blizzard Games
>
> - Diablo II
> - Diablo II: Lord of Destruction
> - StarCraft II
> - StarCraft Anthology
> - Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos
> - Warcraft III: The Frozen Throne
>
> ***Note***: Battle.net Balance may only be used on digital versions of the above games at this time. Battle.net Balance cannot be used to
>   purchase physical copies of these games through the Blizzard Store. 
>   Additionally, World of Warcraft Character and Guild Services are
>   currently unavailable for purchase using AUD.

Answer (score 5):

You can buy other games with it; if I ever use RMAH and get money off it then I'll just use that to get 'free' Diablo 2, Warcraft 3 (which I have BC but it's lost) etc.

Unfortunately, one thing you can't do currently is buy subscriptions, which would have worked far better for the large population of WoW users.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider using the $$ for Wow: MoP and SC2: HotS. Shame it can't be used for subs though.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a second account or a friend you trust you can have him set up an auction for something very specific, at an unusual price level so that you can find his item on the AH and then just buy it.

Obviously this item will have to be listed as a PayPal item so you will get the money out of Blizzard's trap, but there you have it.

How you get the money from PayPal is an entirely different story, but I've been told gifts are not subject to additional fees (within the PayPal system) so getting the money from your friend's PayPal to your own shouldn't incur additional fees.

Comment: Er, won't this incur even MORE fees from Blizzard?  I thought it was possible to withdraw funds from your Blizzard account to your paypal account at any time (and just pay the 15% paypal fee later)?

Comment: No, the FAQ clearly states that you cannot withdraw money. I don't know why, just that that's the way things are. :/ Either way, my way or not, you'd still have to pay the PayPal fee, yes. And another yes; that is more fees, but probably not more than you had envisioned.